# Wrong coping of cell's background color from one XLSX file to another using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I faced a problem when I tried to get a cell background color from one XSLX file and set this color as cell's background to another XSLX file.

Both input and output files are in 2007 (XLSX) format (input file was created with MS Excel 2010).

For working with XLSX files I use Apache Poi 3.14:

```
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("forRead.xlsx");
    Workbook wb_in = WorkbookFactory.create(is);

    XSSFCell cell_in = (XSSFCell) wb_in.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0);

    XSSFColor background_in = ((XSSFColor) cell_in.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor());

    XSSFColor background_out = new XSSFColor();

    background_out.setARGBHex(background_in.getARGBHex()); // this works wrong :(.

    XSSFWorkbook wb_out = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet_out = wb_out.createSheet();
    Row row_out = sheet_out.createRow((short) 2);

    XSSFCell cell_out = (XSSFCell)row_out.createCell((short)1);
    XSSFCellStyle style_out = wb_out.createCellStyle();
    style_out.setFillForegroundColor(background_out); //  if I use background_in, then the output color will be correct
    style_out.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    cell_out.setCellStyle(style_out);

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("forWrite.xlsx");
    wb_out.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```

Result color in output file is singnificantly different. It's darker.
That is a problem I don't know how to solve.

Beside it I noticed two strange things:

1) `background_in.getARGBHex()` gets different color that I saw in Excel. `#F79646 or rgb(247, 150, 70)` instead of `#fde9d9 or rgb(253, 233, 217)`

2) color in output file will be correct if I do `style_out.setFillForegroundColor(background_in);` This makes me think that I could solve the propblem by setting some addition properties like `alpha` or something else for XSSFColor object.

My Maven project can be downloaded 
[from here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3iqPyNbCXLEOFQ0cVp0bHZGNGs). XLSX files are included.

**UPDATE: SOLVED**

I should have set tint in addition to RGB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared I should add setting of tint property in addition to RGB.
back_XSSFColor_out.setTint(back_XSSFColor_in.getTint());